# Prevent users from changing membership type when they renew?

Tags: civimember, renewals

Does anyone know an easy way to prevent users from changing membership type when they renew via the renewal page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Does your membership renewal page show multiple membership-type options?

You may need to set up different membership renewal pages for different membership type.

Comment: This is exactly what we do - each membership type has its own page. The only exception is some have a 1 year, 2 year, and 3 year option, and those are on the same page. But otherwise, each membership type has its own signup/renewal page.

Comment: We want/need to do something like this. We have a trial membership, we don't want them to renew to trial again. Any guidance on how to set this up?

Also, if they user goes unauthenticated to our Join/Signup page they can select Trial Membership. Is there a way to raise an error if that member (email match I guess) already has a trial membership or ANY membership record?